# delay of startup applications, dropbox specifically

Tags: 13.04, mount, startup, dropbox

I have a mounting/dropbox/startup issue. I want to postpone the startup of dropbox, as my computer does not mount the disk in time, and dropbox assumes it is not there. Does anyone know an easy way of delaying the startup of Dropbox? I found another answer in which you manually mount the drive, but I do not want to go that route, I simply want to adjust the time or order in which dropbox is started, maybe put it very last in the 'startup queue' or whatever is used in this circumstance. Thanks much

Answer (score 4):

Open the startup applications window. Just open the Dash ant type startup it should show there. It will looks like this (but in english):

[image]

Select dropbox, push edit. Now at the start of the command line type:

```
sleep 10;
```

So that it all looks like

```
sleep 10;dropbox start -i
```

Now the computer should wait 10 seconds before dropbox starts. You can change the number 10 in the example if you desire a bigger or shorter wait.

Comment: You are the best! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: If this works, remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: This didn't work for me. With and without a space after the semi-colon in the command, it now just boots up and shows no error, which means that Dropbox doesn't run at all.

Comment: You don't need any space. I don't know what you are trying to do or why do you expect an error. But try to drop the -i at the end.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me for flatpak-ed geary

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just add delays to the files in:

```
~/.desktop/autostart/someapp.desktop
```

Edit it with a text editor of your choice and add the delay with the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=999
```

In units of seconds.

Comment: This works in general, but Dropbox clobbers the .desktop file on every start up, over-writing any changes you make.  Haven't found any other app this sloppy yet, but there may be others.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this for my Thunderbird email app.  Currently in Autostart I have this:

```
sleep 10;thunderbird
```

Seems to work great.

That fact that sleep is a utility and not an internal command makes this super easy!!